# xhr 404 response shows custom error page

Tags: ajax, http-status-code-404

I am using mvc5 and have configured an aspx error page for my application. There is an ajax call that returns a 404 and my custom error page is fetched for the ajax 404 response. I don't want my custom error page to be shown for xhr 404 response. Could you please help me resolve this?
for dotnet errors:

```
<system.web>
   <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage.aspx" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
   </customErrors>
```

for iis errors:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode='-1' />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode='-1' />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode='-1' />
      <error statusCode="403" path="/ErrorPage.html" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/ErrorPage.html" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
     <error statusCode="500" path="/ErrorPage.html" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add [mcve] so we can see the problematic code parts?

Comment: <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage.aspx" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
   
</customErrors>